# Jasper exception occurring while trying to include a jsp page with dynamic URL

Tags: java, jsp, jspinclude

Please look at the following code snippet and let me know what's wrong with that as I'm getting the below errors when trying to run it.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The jsp:param action must not be used outside the jsp:include, jsp:forward, or jsp:params elements

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Expecting "jsp:param" standard action with "name" and "value" attributes
```

Here's the code I'm trying to execute

```
<%
    String contextRoot = request.getContextPath();
    String stdInfoViewURL = contextRoot.concat("jsp/student/ViewStudentDetails.jsp"):
%>

<html><body>

<jsp:include page="<%=stdInfoViewURL%>" flush="true">

    <jsp:param name="studentId" value="ABC123" />
    <jsp:param name="studentName" value="MARK TAYLOR" />

</jsp:include>

</body></html>
```

I tried even declaring the java objects in following manner too. But no luck.

```
<%!
    String contextRoot = request.getContextPath();
    String stdInfoViewURL = contextRoot.concat("jsp/student/ViewStudentDetails.jsp"):
%>
```

Comment: are you still getting the error after adding `<jsp:param>` inside `<jsp:include>`? Because I did not get that error when i copy pasted your code

Comment: Yes. I'm getting error. I even tried including them inside <jsp:params> also.

Comment: is the `<jsp:include ...` at line 2062 of CorpUserAddNew.jsp

Comment: yes. but ignore that.. code is same. please let me know the error.

Comment: did you add `jsp:include` recently or was it there before?

Comment: it was there before. i have written previously as <jsp:include page="../../ViewStudentDetails.jsp". but i had to change to dynamic url now. then onwards i am facing the issue

Comment: my doubt is like it is not able to get the exact location of the file. Do you have any guess about how to point out directly to root of the application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160770/discussion-between-nak-and-hari-krishna).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit the `contextRoot` from your `stdInfoViewURL` and just do

`String stdInfoViewURL = "/jsp/student/ViewStudentDetails.jsp":`